# one promise resolve with two different types

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, resolve

I ended up having a promise like this in my code. Is it ok if I resolve in some condition with value of token which is a string `(resolve(token))` and in one other condition resolve with another promise of type `Promise<string>` : `resolve(resultPromise);`

```
const finalPromise = new Promise<string>(resolve => {
    resultPromise.then(token => {
        if (Pending) {      
            resolve(token);
        } else if (!this.tokenIsValid(token)) {
            resultPromise = requestToken();
            resolve(resultPromise);
        } else {
            resolve(token);
        }
    });
```

I also tried changing it like this and got this typescript error:

> //throwing error error noUnnecessaryCallbackWrapper: No need to
>   wrap 'resolve' in another function. Just use it directly.

```
#second verison
    const finalPromise = new Promise<string>(resolve => {
    resultPromise.then(token => {
        if (Pending) {      
            resolve(token);
        } else if (!this.tokenIsValid(token)) {
            requestToken().then(token => resolve(token)); 
        } else {
            resolve(token);
        }
    });
```

What would be the type of finalPromise in case I am returning `resolve(resultPromise)`? what I am concerned is there is another function which gets the `finalPromise` and the type of the input is `Promise<string>` and I am worried that I am messing up responses and I am not aware.
How should I rewrite this so that finalPromise returns Promise of type string? 
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: would it be ... *any*?

Comment: what will happen if there is another function waiting to get the finalPromise as type of Promise<string>?

Comment: sorry, I don't know typescript very well, just seen `<any>` bandied about - guess you could try - thing is, your code is guilty of the [Promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) so it's annoying to read :p

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed in comments you are using Promise constructor anti-pattern, to avoid this you have to chain your code to `resultPromise` directly.

Moreover you can simplify the management of `requestToken` call by returning it:

> Normally, a value returned by a .then handler is immediately passed to the next handler. But there’s an exception.
>
> If the returned value is a promise, then the further execution is suspended until it settles. After that, the result of that promise is given to the next .then handler.

(Quoted from [this article](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining#returning-promises))

So you will end up with something like this:

```
const finalPromise: Promise<string> = resultPromise.then(token => {
    if (Pending) {      
        return token;
    } else if (!this.tokenIsValid(token)) {
        return requestToken();
    } else {
        return token;
    }
);

// Later 
finalPromise.then(stringToken => console.log(stringToken));
```

if-else statement can be simplify too but as I didn't know the type of `Pending` I didn't do it.

---

FYI: It was not your case here but if you really need someday to have multiple return types DO NOT USE `any` but use [union type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) instead:

```
myAwesomeFunctionReturnStringOrNumber(): string | number {
   ...
};

myOtherFunctionTakeStringOrNumber(param: string | number) {
   ...
};
```